# MyQL trigger to limit the number of rows in a table

Tags: mysql

I want to limit the number of users registering on our website, I have written a short Trigger on MySql

```
               BEGIN
                 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt FROM walker;
                 IF @cnt >= 10 THEN
                 CALL sth(); -- What do I put here to stop more people from 
                 registering?
                 END IF;
               END
```

But I don't know how to stop more than 10 people from registering. Is it even possible?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: You can do anything that will raise an error, including simply raising an error with e.g. `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000';`. Although I would think at least (!) twice about if you don't want to move that logic directly into your website.

Answer (score 0):

I think it'll not be a good idea to implement trigger for this situation. Implement a query when the sign up page lands.

$registered_users = Select count(*) from walker.

if $registered_users<$allowed_users go ahead with sign ups otherwise show sorry at the moment we're open to new user registrations.